# Astonishing affinity of Wolfram's rule 110 to the numbers 2 and 7

Tags: prime-numbers, experimental-mathematics, cellular-automata, limit-cycles, visualization

I investigated the evolution of a single black cell on 1-dimensional grids with periodic boundary conditions of variable sizes $N$ under Wolfram's [rule 110](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_110#Interesting_properties) which is the only one for which Turing completeness has been directly proven.

I especially determined by brut force calculation the length $\lambda_{110}(N) = \lambda(N)$ of the limit cycle the single black cell evolves to. Plotting logarithmically the limit cycle lengths for rule 110 and $N = 6\dots 250$ looks like this, the longest limit cycle having length $\lambda = 419,064 = 228 \cdot 2 \cdot 919 $ for $N=228$:

[image]

I normalized the spectrum by considering $\kappa(N) = \lambda(N)/N$.

[image]

This spectrum with its intricate structure is unique among all elementary cellular automata. Furthermore rule 110 is one of only a few non-trivial class III and class IV rules for which $\lambda(N)$ could be computed for all $N \leq 250$. (For rule 106 the algorithm didn't return in reasonable time even for $N=29$.) The other rules' spectra look either much more chaotic or boringly simple. I analyzed the spectrum for different properties.

- For how many $N$ is $\lambda(N) < N$, i.e. $\kappa(N) < 1$?
- Which values $\lambda$ does $\lambda(N) < N$ take?
- For how many $N$ is $\kappa(N)$ an integer number, i.e. $\lambda(N) \equiv 0 \text{ mod }N$?
- Which $\kappa$ have many $N$ with $\kappa(N) = \kappa$ (seen as progressions in the plots above)?
- Which $\kappa$ are unique, i.e. there is only one $N \leq 250$ with $\kappa(N) = \kappa$?

The results of the analysis are summarized here:

[image]

On a logarithmic scale in horizontal direction (the $\kappa$ axis) the number of grid sizes $N$ with $\kappa(N) = \kappa$ or $\lambda(N) = \lambda$ (blue) is plotted. There are

- several $N$ with $\lambda(N) = 7$
- one $N$ with $\lambda(N) = 9$
- many $N$ with $\kappa(N) = 2, 10, 15, 30$
- many $N$ with $\kappa(N) = \frac{3}{2}, \frac{15}{4}, \frac{15}{2}$
- many $N$ with unique $\kappa(N)$, most of them for $\kappa > 59$ and many of them prime or semi-prime.

I calculated the cumulated probabilities $P(N) = \frac{|\{ n \leq N\,|\,p(n)\}|}{N}$ for these properties:

[image]

Let me make three simple conjectures for Wolfram's rule 110, based on these observations:

> There are infinitely many $N$ with $\lambda(N)= 7$.
>
> For almost all $N$ with $\lambda(N) < N$ we find $\lambda(N)= 7$.
>
> There are infinitely many $N$ with $\kappa(N) = 2$.

My question is: **How would one try to prove these conjectures?**

---

Some limit cycles of length $7$ for rule 110:

[image]

With transitions (transients). For $N=87$ the limit cycle isn't reached, yet.

[image]

Approaching limit cycles of length $\lambda = 2\cdot N$. For $N=48,58,64$ the limit cycles aren't reached, yet.

[image]

Comment: What do the spacetime diagrams look like that lead to short limit cycles? Is there some obvious structure that you could extrapolate?

Comment: @IlkkaTörmä: Is your question about transients? I'll add this information. Maybe in a scatterplot that correlates cycle and transient length.

Comment: There is an obvious structure to the non-cyclic configuration with a single initial dot -- spacetime is semilinear, there's just a few gliders going around. If we want to know what happens with large sizes, one could restrict to cycles where you reach this eventual behavior before you reach the end of the cycle. I looked at one of the collisions that can happen, and it seems to stabilize again. So I wouldn't be surprised if this can be fully analyzed (and whatever you are seeing is just an initial phenomenon). But there are hundreds of cases to consider (I didn't even fully consider one case).

Comment: In particular, I don't think looking at cycle lengths below 3000 will tell you much about the eventual behavior.

Comment: @VilleSalo: Don't you think the observed spectra (with $N \leq 250$) will continue to look essentially the same for $N \leq 3000$ and beyond? But I believe it's not feasible to calculate the exact cycle lengths for arbitrarily large $N$ in reasonable time. Or do you know a trick to circumvent brut force calculation?

Comment: It might feasible to analyze the behavior on large enough cycles. Specifically, large enough means far beyond 3000, which is about when the infinite spacetime settles. But that would be a huge undertaking and in principle at any point you could run into something that's impossible to analyze. Possibly very quickly, I just looked at one random situation.

Comment: "Huge" because you have a glider gun with a period of over 200 feeding into one border, and a glider with period 17 or something on the other, and the cycle size determines how they collide. Some of the collisions may lead into new case analyses. Things tend to settle down in 110 (in my very limited experience), so I would not be surprised if the case analysis is finite, but you have to do it, and it's not so easy to computer-assist it.

Comment: @VilleSalo: Where does the number $N=3000$ come from? Why does infinite spacetime start to be settled at this size? Why not at $N=1000$ or $N=10000$ oŕ any other finite number?

Comment: Just run it for ~4000 steps and you'll see it immediately.

Comment: @VilleSalo: What I have learnt from your comments: I have to think of gliders with their own periods, and the overall period is the least common multiple. So part of the question is: how many gliders do emerge? BTW: I find it hard to see the examples for $\lambda =7$  as gliders. Can you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138878/discussion-between-hans-peter-stricker-and-ville-salo).

Comment: @IlkkaTörmä: I added some spacetime diagrams that lead to limit cycles of length $7$.

Comment: Where is the affinity suggested in the title for 3 and 5?

Comment: @MattF.: I found it in the many $N$ with $\kappa(N) = 2, 2\cdot 5, 3\cdot 5, 2\cdot 3 \cdot 5$ and the many $N$ with $\kappa(N) = \frac{3}{2}, \frac{3 \cdot 5}{2 \cdot 2}, \frac{3\cdot 5}{2}$.

Comment: One may ask, why $\kappa(N) = 2\cdot 3, 3 \cdot 3$ and so on are rare or even missing.

Comment: In turn, $\kappa(N) = 36 = 2\cdot 2\cdot 3 \cdot 3$ is frequent.

Comment: Obviously, $\kappa = 4 = 2\cdot 2$ is also missing.

Comment: The smallest ten numbers are all products (including the empty product) of 2, 3, 5 and 7, and the fractions with smallest numerators and denominators therefore are all products and quotients of 2, 3, 5, and 7 — and in the analysis of this cellular automaton, small numbers occur more frequently than large numbers. The numbers answering particular questions can still be interesting, but the appearance of this group of numbers is not what I would call astonishing.

Comment: @MattF. I'll remove 3 and 5 from the title.