# Possible shifts in finite elementary cellular automata

Tags: nt.number-theory, experimental-mathematics, cellular-automata, limit-cycles, visualization

I investigated the long term behaviour of a pair of black cells ■■ on a circle of $N$ cells under the action of each of Wolfram's rules $R$. For each combination $(R,N)$ I determined the first occurrence of a pattern $\pi$ that re-appears $\lambda$ time steps later, shifted by $\sigma$ cells, being the start of a limit cycle. These numbers are enough to tell the [length of the limit cycle](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429380/astonishing-affinity-of-wolframs-rule-110-to-the-numbers-2-and-7) which is given by

$$L(R,N) = \frac{N}{\text{gcd}(N,\sigma)}\cdot \lambda$$

or equivalently by

$$L(R,N) = \frac{\text{lcm}(N,\sigma)}{v}$$

with $v$ being the "velocity" of the pattern $\pi$, $v = \sigma / \lambda$.

All I did was to plot the velocities for a given rule $R$ in a $\sigma$-$\lambda$ diagram choosing a logarithmic scale for $\lambda$. The shading of the dots indicates multiplicities, i.e. the number of $N$ for which the velocity is achieved. The colors indicate to which of Wolfram's ECA classes the data point belongs, especially green for class IV, blue for class III, red for class II.

**All rules**

[image]

There are proper velocities $v \leq 1$ (above the diagonal, $\lambda \geq \sigma$) and pseudo-velocities $v > 1$ (below the diagonal).

The diagram with class I rules only contains only one dot $(\sigma = 0, \lambda = 1)$.

**Class II rules**

[image]

**Class III rules**

[image]

**Class IV rules**

[image]

Most of the dots here come from rule 110. Rules 41 and 106 don't contribute too much and behave more like class III rules –  for this special start configuration!

**Rule 110**

[image]

Rule 54 gives the (pseudo-)diagonal with $\lambda = \sigma -1$.

**Rule 54**

[image]

---

Having said and showed this I'd like to ask:

> Is there a general procedure to decide if for given $\sigma, \lambda$ there is a rule $R$ and a circle length $N$ giving rise to them? Or – equivalently? – a enumeration of such $\sigma, \lambda$ that is not just brut force calculation?

I think of generating functions as Wolfram uses them in
his paper [Algebraic Properties of Cellular Automata](https://content.wolfram.com/uploads/sites/34/2020/07/algebraic-properties-cellular-automata.pdf). But the
paper is mostly about rule 90, and I am not able to generalize the
approach.

In case the question has to be answered to the negative (as some comments seem to suggest):

> Can it be predicted or proved that the $\sigma$-$\lambda$-plot must
> have the general properties it has (regardless of single rules and exact values):
>
> - the existence of a (pseudo-)diagonal?
> - distinguished gapless horizontal baselines extending to infinity?
> - distinguished gapless horizontal lines ending at the diagonal?
> - distinguished horizontal lines starting at the diagonal extending to infinity?

From an answer to this main question, answers to the following sub-questions could be derived:

- Why do the horizontal lines that end at the diagonal correspond to $\lambda = 2^k$ for $k \geq 3$.
- Why do the (visible) horizontal lines that start at the diagonal correspond to $\lambda = 1, 2, 4, 15, 30, 36, 64$ which is not the beginning of any OEIS sequence?
- Why is the diagonal for rule 54 only a pseudo-diagonal, i.e. $\lambda = \sigma - 1$?
- Why does rule 110 for $N=1\dots 250$ exhibit multiple velocities only for four velocities:

  - $(\sigma = 0, \lambda = 7)$ with multiplicity $25/250$
  - $(\sigma = 2, \lambda = 3)$ with multiplicity $23/250$
  - $(\sigma = 2, \lambda = 10)$ with multiplicity $13/250$
  - $(\sigma = 10, \lambda = 1)$ with multiplicity $6/250$

---

**Suppementary material**

The same diagrams as above but without coloring (for classes) and shading (for multiplicities):

**All rules**

[image]

**Class II rules**

[image]

**Class III rules**

[image]

**Class IV rules**

[image]

**Rule 110**

[image]

**Rule 54**
[image]

---

Transitions to $\pi$ (the start of the limit cycle, green/red), its shifts, and the limit cycles (blue) for rule 110 and $N=6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,16,17$:

[image: 6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,16,17]

Comment: Way too many subquestions. E.g. the first question is approachable but really already 256 questions in one.

Comment: @VilleSalo: You mean 88 questions in one;-)

Comment: @VilleSalo: I modified the questions section.

Comment: @VilleSalo: My question is: What do the 88 approaches have in common? Are they all based on generating functions?

Comment: If I understood the quantifiers in the question correctly, I would guess that the problem "Given a cellular automaton $R$ and parameters $(\sigma,\lambda)$, does there exist an $N$ such that a pair of black cells on a circle of length $N$ evolve into a limit cycle with $(\sigma,\lambda)$?" is undecidable (with $R$ not restricted to be elementary).

Comment: @JohanKopra: Thanks for the comment. I tried to clear the question and to clarify the quantifiers.

Comment: "What do the 88 approaches have in common?" Probably nothing, but I did not look at all of them. For the same reason, I don't claim to know whether your question (for a fixed $R$, is it decidable whether $(\lambda, \sigma$ appears for rule $R$) is decidable for all rules $R$. "Are they all based on generating functions?" There is no reason to expect that something that works for rule 90 (which is linear) works for anything nonlinear.